# using jquery plugin jquery selectboxit by greg franko,

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using jquery plugin jquery selectboxit by greg franko, can we render 2 different styling for 2 different select boxes in a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Since SelectBoxIt will copy over any class names from your original select box to the new drop down, you can use this to create many different styles for your drop downs:

Here is an example CSS class that is applying a small width for a drop down:

```
.small-dropdown.selectboxit, .small-dropdown.selectboxit + .selectboxit-options{
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;    
}
```

In your HTML you would then use your class like this:

```
<select class="small-dropdown">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgzDX/64/) example of this technique.